# I'm having an issue with LINQ and Namespaces

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am trying to use LINQ in a C# application to extract information from an xml file where the values are greater than a number parameter.  The xml uses namespaces that are not urls.  I've been looking at similar StackOverflow questions and all seem to have a url for a namespace - like xmlns="http://www.cgi.com/Ratabase", but mine look like xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" and xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema".

Here is a snippet of the xml:

```
<configurations>
<system_config>
    <section id="rs_centerinfo">
        <xml xmlns:s="uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882" xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema">
            <s:Schema id="RowsetSchema">
                <s:ElementType name="row" content="eltOnly" rs:updatable="true">
                    <s:AttributeType name="CenterCode" rs:number="1" rs:write="true">
                        <s:datatype dt:type="string" dt:maxLength="8" rs:precision="0" rs:maybenull="false"/>
                    </s:AttributeType>
                    <s:AttributeType name="CenterName" rs:number="2" rs:write="true">
                        <s:datatype dt:type="string" dt:maxLength="30" rs:precision="0" rs:maybenull="false"/>
                    </s:AttributeType>
                    <s:AttributeType name="Version" rs:number="3" rs:write="true">
                        <s:datatype dt:type="string" dt:maxLength="5" rs:precision="0" rs:maybenull="false"/>
                    </s:AttributeType>
                    <s:AttributeType name="NextExport" rs:number="4" rs:write="true">
                        <s:datatype dt:type="int" dt:maxLength="4" rs:precision="0" rs:fixedlength="true" rs:maybenull="false"/>
                    </s:AttributeType>
                    <s:AttributeType name="NextImport" rs:number="5" rs:write="true">
                        <s:datatype dt:type="int" dt:maxLength="4" rs:precision="0" rs:fixedlength="true" rs:maybenull="false"/>
                    </s:AttributeType>
                    <s:AttributeType name="LastImportTime" rs:number="6" rs:write="true">
                        <s:datatype dt:type="dateTime" rs:dbtype="variantdate" dt:maxLength="16" rs:precision="0" rs:fixedlength="true" rs:maybenull="false"/>
                    </s:AttributeType>
                    <s:AttributeType name="FtpProxyServer" rs:number="7" rs:write="true">
                        <s:datatype dt:type="string" dt:maxLength="40" rs:precision="0" rs:maybenull="false"/>
                    </s:AttributeType>
                    <s:AttributeType name="FtpUserName" rs:number="8" rs:write="true">
                        <s:datatype dt:type="string" dt:maxLength="20" rs:precision="0" rs:maybenull="false"/>
                    </s:AttributeType>
                    <s:AttributeType name="FtpPassword" rs:number="9" rs:write="true">
                        <s:datatype dt:type="string" dt:maxLength="20" rs:precision="0" rs:maybenull="false"/>
                    </s:AttributeType>
                    <s:AttributeType name="ResetImportID" rs:number="10" rs:write="true">
                        <s:datatype dt:type="boolean" dt:maxLength="2" rs:precision="0" rs:fixedlength="true" rs:maybenull="false"/>
                    </s:AttributeType>
                    <s:extends type="rs:rowbase"/>
                </s:ElementType>
            </s:Schema>
            <rs:data>
                <z:row CenterCode="JAX" CenterName="Jacksonville" Version="1.0" NextExport="66742" NextImport="29756" LastImportTime="2015-06-10T14:48:33" FtpProxyServer="" FtpUserName="" FtpPassword="" ResetImportID="False"/>
                <z:row CenterCode="PHL" CenterName="Philadelphia" Version="1.0" NextExport="78993" NextImport="74506" LastImportTime="2015-06-10T14:48:35" FtpProxyServer="" FtpUserName="" FtpPassword="" ResetImportID="False"/>
                <z:row CenterCode="AGS" CenterName="Augusta" Version="1.0" NextExport="82040" NextImport="9893" LastImportTime="2015-06-10T13:02:39" FtpProxyServer="" FtpUserName="" FtpPassword="" ResetImportID="False"/>
                <z:row CenterCode="TYS" CenterName="Knoxville" Version="1.0" NextExport="74756" NextImport="15509" LastImportTime="2011-07-25T14:46:48" FtpProxyServer="" FtpUserName="" FtpPassword="" ResetImportID="False"/>
```

I'm trying to select attributes from z:row where NextImport and NextExport are greater than 50000 into a list in order to display in a grid.

**EDIT:**  I'm not sure how to code my selection in LINQ.  I'm trying to get something back using the following code:

```
            XDocument xmldoc = XDocument.Load(@"c:\XML\Configuration.xml");
        XNamespace rs = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset";
        XNamespace z = "#RowsetSchema";
        string test = xmldoc.Descendants(z + "row").Attributes("NextExport").ToString();
```

Comment: How are we supposed to tell you where the error in your code is, if you don't post any?

Comment: Try this : string test = xmldoc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "row").Attributes("NextExport").ToString();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of namespaces looks good.  So, a query to find all `{#RowsetSchema}row` rows with NextImport and NextExport > 50000 would look like

```
        XNamespace z = "#RowsetSchema";

        var limit = 50000L;
        var elementQuery = xmldoc.Descendants(z + "row").Where(e => (long?)e.Attribute("NextExport") > limit && (long?)e.Attribute("NextImport") > limit);
```

(The `(long?)` casting handles the case where the attributes are missing.)

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "I'm trying to select attributes from ... into a list".  If you want a list of the elements themselves, do:

```
        var elements = elementQuery.ToList();
```

If you want just the `NextImport` and `NextExport` attributes in the grid, you can do something like:

```
        var attributePairs = elementQuery.Select(e => new[] { (string)e.Attribute("NextExport"), (string)e.Attribute("NextImport") }).ToList();
```

If you want all attributes in the grid, you can start with something like:

```
        var attributes = elementQuery.Select(e => e.Attributes().Select(a => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(a.Name.LocalName, (string)a)).ToList()).ToList();
```

Bear in mind that the XML standard defines attributes to be [unordered](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-attr) so there's no guarantee that the attributes will appear in the same order from row to row.

Comment: Thanks @dbc !  I'm only looking for 3 other attributes besides NextImport and NextExport to display in the grid, but you have shown me how to select them.  I'm very new to linq so much appreciated.  I also have nott used the C# grid control before but it should accept a list as  a data source,  Marked as answer.